# What's the difference between protect_from_forgery and verify_authenticity_token in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I usually write `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` in my API controllers but I just found out there is also an option of `protect_from_forgery except :action`. What are the differences and when should I be using which one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Looking at the code for `protect_from_forgery`, it's a wrapper around `verify_authenticity_token` and `verify_same_origin_request`.

```
def protect_from_forgery(options = {})
  options = options.reverse_merge(prepend: false)

  self.forgery_protection_strategy = protection_method_class(options[:with] || :null_session)
  self.request_forgery_protection_token ||= :authenticity_token
  before_action :verify_authenticity_token, options
  append_after_action :verify_same_origin_request
end
```

My read of [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/RequestForgeryProtection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-protect_from_forgery) is that you use `protect_from_forgery` to turn CSRF on by default for all your controllers in your ApplicationController. Use `skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token` to selectively turn it off in subclasses.